# How to upload files into google drive?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, drive

I am looking to upload files into google drive via nodejs. I want to upload into the google drive of users who log in through google on my site.

Once a user logs into my website via google then I will be given a token. And I can obtain user details, read files using this token. I am unable to find if we can upload files into the user's account using this token. Is it possible ?

Its like, Mr. X logins into my site using google sign in. Then he uploads a file(ex: image and edits it). which on saving i will upload to Mr. X google drive directly.

Answer (score 1):

Check the official [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) and the [Drive API Upload guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads).